# How to create event relay programatically

Tags: rest-api, platform-event

Is there any way to create an event relay programmatically or via the REST API? I've only seen a way to create it from the UI. Including the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ev_relay_create_ui.htm&type=5)

Comment: This is [metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_eventrelayconfig.htm?q=event%20relay) and you'll need the Metadata API